# Use Buttons as a Switch or Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

I try to explain quickly and in detail what I plan to do. 
I have a table, where each cell is placed a button CSS like this:

```
<input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="#"> //a different id for each button
```

My intention is to select (to click) many different buttons; each time a button is selected it has to change color (or to change the class of the button); if is pressed again, it must return to its original state. 
Next, I want a submit button that invokes a servlet and sends which buttons have been selected and which are not.
Now my question: Is it possible to do with JavaScript? If yes, could you kindly share the code necessary to do this? If no, what do you suggest?

Now I share a piece of code involved for this purpose. I'm sorry in advance if I wasn't not much detailed.

HTML

```
<form action="myServlet" method="post">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
       <tr>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="11"/></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="12"/></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="13"/></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="14"/></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="15"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="21"/></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="22"/></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="23"/></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="24"/></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="25"/></td>
       </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

CSS

```
.AreaFree{
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
    background-color:#44c767;
    border:1px solid #18ab29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:15px 21px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.AreaFree:hover {
    background-color:#5cbf2a;
}
.AreaFree:active {
    position:relative;  
}


.AreaOccupated{
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;   
    background-color:#E00000;
    border:1px solid #B00000;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:15px 21px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.AreaOccupated:hover {
    background-color:#D00000;
}
.AreaOccupated:active {
    position:relative;  
}


.AreaBlocked{
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
    background-color:#A8A8A8;
    border:1px solid #808080;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:15px 21px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.AreaBlocked:hover {
    background-color:#989898;
}
.AreaBlocked:active {
    position:relative;  
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use a `checkbox` or `radio` button instead? It's much better at holding state than a `button` is.

Comment: You could use `<input type="checkbox" />` with `<label>` elements to 'pretend' to be a button (if you must): [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g9fofL71/).

Comment: @mariocatch I can't use radio buttons because with them I could just select one element, whereas I need to select many buttons.

Comment: @David Thomas I thought the idea to use the checkboxes, but I'm not able to get a result like this [link](http://i68.tinypic.com/so2wdd.png) If you can reproduce the same result with the checkboxes, show me

Comment: This is what checkboxes are for. you're recreating what already exists.

Comment: I tried to replace the buttons with the checkboxes and to associate them the "AreaFree" class, like this: 
    
    <input type="checkbox" class="AreaFree" id="11"/>

but doesn't working. Can you reproduce the same result please?

Comment: You'll want to give names to your input elements so the server can receive them accordingly in the post handler. Also when you say it's not working, what isn't working exactly? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @mariocatch if you look at Will's answer, He's very very close to the solution. Conceptually, I'm making a grid (similar to Battleship) where each square corresponds to an area. This grid is built dynamically through user input (the user decides the number of rows and columns). Initially, the grid will be made only by green buttons (buttons with class "AreaFree"); when the user presses on a button that must stay pressed and change color, specifically gray (buttons with class "AreaBlocked").

Comment: If I press the button gray, it must return to its original state (green). Finally, via a submit button, I have to send information to the servlet regarding the status of all the buttons, to see which are pressed and which are not. This is a summary of the general problem I have to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to bottom of your html:

```
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function(evt) {
    var ary = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    if (ary.indexOf('clicked') === -1) {
        $(this).addClass('clicked');    
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');    
    }
});
```

Also add this class:

```
input.clicked {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Now, you have to handle the hover color issue, but the code should give you a good start.

UPDATE: (This code works for me)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
    <style>
.AreaFree{
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
    background-color:#44c767;
    border:1px solid #18ab29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:15px 21px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.AreaFree:hover {
    background-color:#5cbf2a;
}
.AreaFree:active {
    position:relative;  
}


.AreaOccupated{
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;   
    background-color:#E00000;
    border:1px solid #B00000;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:15px 21px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.AreaOccupated:hover {
    background-color:#D00000;
}
.AreaOccupated:active {
    position:relative;  
}


.AreaBlocked{
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
    background-color:#A8A8A8;
    border:1px solid #808080;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:15px 21px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.AreaBlocked:hover {
    background-color:#989898;
}
.AreaBlocked:active {
    position:relative;  
}

input.clicked {
    background-color: red;
}

    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
<form action="myServlet" method="post">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
       <tr>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="11"/></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="12"/></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="13"/></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="14"/></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="15"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="21"/></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="22"/></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="23"/></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="24"/></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="25"/></td>
       </tr>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script>
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function(evt) {
  var ary = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
  if (ary.indexOf('clicked') === -1) {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');    
  }
  else {
    $(this).removeClass('clicked');    
  }
});
</script>
   </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <style>
        .AreaFree {
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
            background-color: #44c767;
            border: 1px solid #18ab29;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 15px 21px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .AreaFree:hover {
            background-color: #5cbf2a;
        }

        .AreaFree:active {
            position: relative;
        }

        .AreaOccupated {
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
            background-color: #E00000;
            border: 1px solid #B00000;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 15px 21px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .AreaOccupated:hover {
            background-color: #D00000;
        }

        .AreaOccupated:active {
            position: relative;
        }

        .AreaBlocked {
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
            background-color: #A8A8A8;
            border: 1px solid #808080;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 15px 21px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .AreaBlocked:hover {
            background-color: #989898;
        }

        .AreaBlocked:active {
            position: relative;
        }

        input.clicked {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="myServlet" method="post">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="0" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="1" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="2" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="3" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="4" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="5" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="6" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="7" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="8" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="9" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <input type="hidden" id="matrix" value="" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

    <script>
        var matrix = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            matrix.push(0);
        }
        // set the hidden field on init
        $('#matrix').val(matrix);
        $('input[type="button"]').on('click', function(evt) {
            var me = $(this);
            var idx = +me.attr('id'); // the + sign turns this value to a number
            if (matrix[idx] === 0) {
                matrix[idx] = 1;
                me.addClass('clicked');
            } else {
                matrix[idx] = 0;
                me.removeClass('clicked');
            }
            // update the hidden field every time a user clicks something
            $('#matrix').val(matrix);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I did a few things in the latest code.  Since we are tracking the states in a matrix array, no need to get look at the class.  Use the state in matrix to determine.  Comparing 0 and 1 are quicker than strings and array.

I also changed the button ID's to help update the matrix.

Comment: I tried but doesn't work. I added the first block after the </html> tag and the class in the css file, but no result.

Comment: I just updated with the actual page that works for me.  You said you added after the </html> tag.  Nothing should ever go after </html> tag.

Comment: Very good! Thank you so much, but I've some doubts: 
When I will call the servlet by the submit button, how will I know (in the servlet) if a button is pressed (then is red) or not? When I use the request (type HttpServletRequest) object, what kind of operation I have to do to know this information? I thought to a Boolean, but how could I associate a Boolean to a button?
I was planning to replace buttons with the checkbox, but could I have the same result?

Comment: @Zoythrus - You should keep an array with the states of the buttons and update them as you click them.  So when you make that server call, you send the data in that array.  Unless you have a need for the UI to be check boxes, I suggest using button.  Also, give bootstrap a tried, it has tons of out-of-the-box css you can use.

Comment: What a good idea to use a boolean matrix with rows and columns, could I ask you this last favor to upgrade your code, adding this matrix with this information? I unfortunately don't know how to write the scripts, I am a beginner and I'm not able yet.

For example the first button is array[1,1], the second is array[1,2] ... the first button under the previous is the array[2,1] etc.

Comment: That's a good solution, but I would like to ask you something: I usually use the <input type="hidden" value="action" name="whatsend"> to know which action I need to do in the servlet. In the servlet I request the parameter value of "whatsend" and I launch a series of checks if(whatsend.equals("action"){ ... } else if(whatsend.equals("action_2") etc.

Comment: To solve the problem, can I simply insert another input type hidden? And in the Servlet, to get the array of booleans, could I just do "int arrayBoolean[] = request.getParameter ("matrix");"? Is this line of code correct? Or should I fix it and add the size of the array?

Comment: @Zoytrus - Using a hidden field to store the matrix array is exactly what you should do.  As to reading the hidden field on the server, try it, and if you have issues, post another question in that language tag.  Hearing Servelet, I assume Java and I don't do Java.

Comment: However, I've changed a little thing is your script, I just put this:

me.addClass('AreaBlocked');

me.removeClass('AreaBlocked');

Is it the same thing? Or not?

Comment: @Zoythrus - addClass and removeClass are correct functions to use using jquery.  I'm answering your question out of context though.

Comment: Forgive my delay Will, but I have a question, Could you use a two-dimensional array instead of a one-dimensional array? Something like "var matrix = [][];" If possible, could you attach to this solution, the solution with two-dimensional array please? Thank you in advance, sorry again.

Comment: @Zoythrus - Do you want to start a jsfiddle and I'm happy to update it.  Start someting and I'm happy to finish it if necessary.  Note: 2 dimensional array is var ary = [ [1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6] ].  Notice thw brackets inside the main bracket.